# redissoon error: Redis url should start with redis:// or rediss://

Tags: redisson

I am upgrading from redisson 3.3.0 to 3.15.6.

Expected

`mvn clean install` runs with zero failures.

Actual

Multiple test failures that are related to the following error:

```
[org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redissonClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Redis url should start with redis:// or rediss://
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url format has been changed since `3.4.3` version. `redis://` or `rediss://` prefix should be used.

Comment: What kind of answer is that..? :D